# Data is not saved in mysql - springboot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, multithreading, spring-data-jpa

I am having a strange issue, I am trying to insert data (50000) using multi-thread, though I cannot see any exceptions/errors in the log but still data is not persisted in the DB.

Can you please let me know what is wrong with this code?

```
@Retryable(
        value = { Exception.class },
        maxAttempts = 3,
        backoff = @Backoff(delay = 5000))
@Transactional
public void insertBatch(List<Customer> batch) {
    int numThreads = 4; // Set the number of threads
    int batchSize = 1000; // Set the batch size

    List<List<Customer>> partitions = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < batch.size(); i += batchSize) {
        int end = Math.min(i + batchSize, batch.size());
        partitions.add(batch.subList(i, end));
    }

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);
    List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

    for (List<Customer> partition : partitions) {
        futures.add(executor.submit(() -> {
            try {
                customerRepository.saveAll(partition);
                log.info("Customer Saved "+ partition.size());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Failed to insert partition: {}", partition, e);
                throw e;
            }
        }));
    }

    for (Future<?> future : futures) {
        try {
            future.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Partition insertion failed", e);
        }
    }

    executor.shutdown();
}

@Recover
public void handleInsertBatchException(Exception e, List<Customer> batch) {
    log.error("Insertion failed for batch: {}", batch, e);
    // Handle the exception here, for example, you can retry with a smaller batch size
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

[GitHub Issue Link](https://github.com/rajarshp/JavaSample/issues/6)

any help appreciated

Comment: Maybe, you want save 500 records, success with first 304 records, error at 305th record, then all records cannot commit (database is rollback). You can debug by `.save()` not `.saveAll()` for testing/debugging. Let's me know result.

Comment: I just tried with a single record with both save and saveAll, I cannot see any error but still, data is not committed to the DB. don't know what the issue is

Comment: Did you tried DB locking mechanism? I feel that this is because of multiple threads trying to insert into same table.

Comment: how to achieve this locking explicitly as I thought Spring will handle this as I am using @Transantional

Answer (score 0):

Default is

```java
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
```

therefore, Use

```java
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
```

- Reference document: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Isolation.html
- See: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-transactional-propagation-isolation

Comment: No, it didn't help, still no data in the DB. The same approach I implemented for MongoDB and it's working perfectly. Not sure what I am missing for this MySQL DB

Comment: there is some problem with this multi-threading, if I insert without three it's working fine